# Running two different projects with different url with same port of single instance of tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I have two different project in tomcat server which runs on same port no.Assume that port is 80.Is it possible access these two projects with different url  lets say one with /admin and other with /tomcat.I am new to tomcat little help in detail would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure. What you call  _URL_ is in fact called _Context_ , and the context name is directly taken from what you find in the webapps directory by default.

Comment: so how would i solve my problem in that case .can i have two context which runs on same port with one instance

Comment: There is no problem. Both applications should be stored in the webapps directory (check what you already find there such as /examples /docs ,.. )